# Laptop in-built Web Cam stopped working HP Probook

Tags: 14.04, hp, webcam

My laptop (HP Probook) webcam has always worked.  When I upgraded to 13.10 it stopped working.  No solution found then so gave up.  Recently upgraded to 14.04  still not working so thought I would ask anyone again if a solution had been found.

`lsusb`

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:62c0 Microdia Sonix USB 2.0 Camera
```

dmesg | grep uvcvideo`

```
[  765.466575] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB 2.0 Camera (0c45:62c0)
[  765.467305] uvcvideo: UVC non compliance - GET_DEF(PROBE) not supported. Enabling workaround.
[  765.467954] uvcvideo: Failed to query (129) UVC probe control : -32 (exp. 26).
[  765.467960] uvcvideo: Failed to initialize the device (-5).
[  765.468022] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
```

Tried searching everywhere but there does not appear to be any clear solution to the driver issue - very weird as my camera is listed as supported by `uvcvideo` and it has always worked.

Comment: How did you test to see if your webcam is working? Try installing Cheese (in the Software Centre) and see if it wont use your webcam

Comment: Skype Video and Cheese both used to work - they no longer work.  Cheese gives me a Device not Found error.

Comment: 'Bus 002 Device 008: ID 045e:00f8 Microsoft Corp. LifeCam NX-6000'


Same issue with the NX-6000. I guess it affects all cams with uvcvideo

Comment: Well blow me away if after some (unfortunately unknown) update my webcam just started working again.

Answer (score 2):

This stuff works for me (Dell XPD, built-in webcam and Ubuntu 14.04): Cheese, Skype do not see any webcam.

1. After logging in, in a terminal :

   ```
   sudo rmmod uvcvideo
   ```
2. Then :

   ```
   sudo modprobe uvcvideo
   ```

A few seconds processing, then done. Cheese, Skype will work properly. But this is a bug !